# Multiple Dependency Injection with same interface and class (C#)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I got a scenario where I have a ServiceBusService class (c#) that take the ServiceBusClient and the queue name. The following is an example right now in the constructor:

```
public MyClass(ServiceBusClient serviceBusClient)
{
    sbs1 = new ServicebusService(serviceBusClient, "queue1");
    sbs2 = new ServicebusService(serviceBusClient, "queue2");
}
```

Is there a way to do dependency injection for this scenario so it's possible to mock it away in the unit tests?

Comment: Add two parameters of type `ServiceBusSerice` to your ctor (and probably delete the `ServiceBusClient`, as it's only needed to construct these two objects)?

Comment: Look at [Keyed services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#keyed-services) (appeared in .NET 8)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with factory delegate. Where you would register named instances for example :

```
    services.AddScoped<Func<string,ServicebusService>>(serviceProvider => key => 
    {
         switch(key)
        {
          case "queue1":
                return new ServicebusService(serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue1");
            case "queue2":
                return new ServicebusService(serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue2");
            default:
                throw new KeyNotFoundException(); // Or return a default implementation
    }
})
```

How to use, you just inject in constructor:

```
public class MyConsumerClass
{
    private readonly Func<string, ServicebusService> _serviceAccessor;

    public MyConsumerClass(Func<string, ServicebusService> serviceAccessor)
    {
        _serviceAccessor = serviceAccessor;
    }
    
    public void DoWork()
   {
      var service = _serviceAccessor("queue1")
   }
}
```

Then you can mock your registration in tests like this:

```
    services.AddScoped<Func<string,ServicebusService>>(serviceProvider => key => 
    {
         switch(key)
        {
          case "queue1":
                return new MockedServiceBus(serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue1");
            case "queue2":
                return new MockedServiceBus(serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue2");
            default:
                throw new KeyNotFoundException(); // Or return a default implementation
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor to the following:

```
public MyClass(ServicebusService sbs1, ServicebusService sbs2)
{
    this.sbs1 = sbs1;
    this.sbs2 = sbs2;
}
```

And change your DI configuration to the following:

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyClass>(sp =>
{
    var serviceBusClient = sp.GerRequiredService<ServiceBusClient>();
    return new MyClass(
        sbs1: new ServicebusService(serviceBusClient, "queue1"),
        sbs2: new ServicebusService(serviceBusClient, "queue2"));
});
```

Or, when `MyClass` isn't interested in differentiating between the two queues, inject a collection:

```
public MyClass(IEnumerable<ServicebusService> sbss)
{
    this.sbss = sbss;
}
```

Your DI configuration now becomes the following:

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
services.AddSingleton<ServicebusService>(sp =>
    new ServicebusService(sp.GerRequiredService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue1"));
services.AddSingleton<ServicebusService>(sp =>
    new ServicebusService(sp.GerRequiredService<ServiceBusClient>(), "queue2"));
```

Comment: I did not down vote, but AddSingleton does not work in my case as I'm disposing the sender in ServicebusService...

Comment: @TommySelggren: The shown lifestyles are just examples, as your question contains too little information about what lifestyles you might require. Adapt accordingly to your needs.